# conditional assignment to string in sh

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I am writing a `docker save` statement for a bunch of images. And there is one image that I want to only save it when certain flag is set to true.

I am proposing something like this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
docker save AA BB CC DD
  if [ "${EE_flag}" = true ]; then
    EE
  fi
       | gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

But it failed because `docker save` is really only expecting some string as arguments, instead of an IF/ELSE statement. I tried ternary operator `? :` but it seems it only work for numerical value.

Is there any tricks in sh can do this?

Comment: What is `EE_flag` set to otherwise? `false`, or is it empty, or unset?

Comment: @BenjaminW. then all other images except for EE will still be saved and packaged.

Comment: I mean, what's the value of the `EE_flag` parameter? Do you control that?

Comment: @BenjaminW. it's either string "true" or "false"

Comment: Ah well, then my idea doesn't work. If you can control that variable and not set it at all or set it to the empty string, you could just use `docker save AA BB CC DD "${EE_flag:+EE}"`, but if it is `false`, that won't work.

Comment: @BenjaminW. `"${EE_flag:+EE}"` always produces an argument, albeit a possibly empty one. You would want the word to disappear completely if the expansion was an empty string (a la `"$@"`).

Comment: @chepner Also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
docker save AA BB CC DD $( [[ $EE_flag = true ]] && echo "EE" ) |
gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

Comment: @Psyduck Yes, `[[ ... ]]` is a Bash feature, but you're running your script with a `/bin/sh` shebang line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. this answer looks like what would solve my problem, but any hint on how to fit to sh syntax?

Comment: @Psyduck Use `[ "$EE_flag" = true ]` instead.

Comment: @Psyduck: You can use: `docker save AA BB CC DD $( [ "$EE_flag" = true ] && echo "EE" ) |
gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz`

Comment: it worked fine in a sh script, but now I have another problem that I want this `docker save ...` command with condition in the Makefile which uses a default /bin/sh shell. Is there any way to modify it?

Comment: @anubhava thanks man, I figured by just adding a shell keyword `$
(shell ...)`

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat repetitive, but will work for all possible arguments to `docker save`:

```
if [ "${EE_flag}" = true ]; then
  docker save AA BB CC DD EE
else
  docker save AA BB CC DD
fi | gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

To reduce the receptiveness, you can make use of the script's positional parameters.

```
set -- AA BB CC DD
[ "${EE_flag}" = true ] && set -- "$@" EE
docker save "$@" | gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

In a more capable shell, you would use an array instead of positional parameters, but POSIX shell does not yet require support for arrays.

Some additional work is required if the script is already using positional parameters. Or, you can define a function (which has its own set of positional parameters) that always saves AA, BB, CC, DD in addition to any other arguments.

```
ds () { docker save AA BB CC DD; }
if [ "${EE_flag}" = true; then
  ds
else
  ds EE
fi | gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help

```
strParams="AA BB CC DD"

if [[ $EE_flag = true ]]; then
    strParams="$strParams EE"
fi

docker save $strParams | gzip -o single-tarball.tar.gz
```

Comment: This fails if any of the arguments themselves need to contain whitespace.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) re: why using strings to store argument lists is bad practice. (anubhava's answer does this too, which is why it -- like this one -- won't work if the conditionally-present arguments need to be quoted, either to permit them to contain characters in IFS as literals or to suppress glob expansion).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy, I will check it